# InfoPath - MOSS User Information List as Data Connection - Exclude groups

Tags: sharepoint, moss, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I have an InfoPath form where I want to place a drop down list to select a user from a MOSS server.

I added a Data Connection in InfoPath to the `User Information List` list in my MOSS server. It works well, but the values I get are:

```
DOMAIN\administrator
SharePoint Owners
SharePoint Visitors
SharePoint Members
NT AUTHORITY\local service
System Account
```

Is there a way in InfoPath (or MOSS) to filter the list so it doesn't include groups?

Bonus question: Is there a way to filter it so system accounts are not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  When you set up the drop down to fill with data from the data connection you can filter the entries for the information that you want. After you have selected the datasource press the button to the right of Entries to select the repeating group that you want.

There is a filter data button on the Select field or group dialog.

From there you can filter the data how you want.

Comment: I had to remove the images from your post because ImageShack has deleted them and replaced them with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!